# Rails rake:migrate gives access denied for 'root'@'localhost' *Ubuntu 16.04*

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xampp

I've been trying to get this figured out for two days now. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to just make a sample app using mysql, and rails. But, every time I try to `rake db:migrate` I get a no access error. I've checked my database.yml file 100 times, and everything looks right. Logging into mysql through the terminal with the exact same login credentials works fine. It seems like mysql is working for everything except for Rails.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  database: my_ror
  pool: 50
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  database: my_ror_development
  pool: 50
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, does the `my_ror_development` (or `my_ror` if problem in not in development env) database exist yet, and have you checked in mysql if the root@localhost user has been granted access to that database? Try running `show grants;` in mysql to check.